# c# web api - How to return ID after post method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a post method that adds the customer into the database. But after the post is finished, what I get as a result in the postman for the CustomerID is always 0.
Other two parameters are working fine(Name and address), and when I check into the database, id field is inserted as it should be.
This is my post method from the controller.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("postCustomerBy")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Customer customer)
    {
        customer = rep.Add(customer);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, customer);
        string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = customer.CustomerID });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }
```

EDIT: This is my function for adding Customers:

```
 public Customer Add(Customer customer)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO Customer(Name,Address) VALUES (@Name,@Address)";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", customer.Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", customer.Address);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            return customer;
        }
    }
```

Comment: show us the code of the function rep.Add()

Comment: It’s not clear from this example whether `CustomerID` is ever truly assigned before the method returns.

Comment: I have edited my question with the method for adding customers

Comment: Please show us the Customer class and the context function.

Comment: No where do you retrieve an id for the created record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID` and affect the returned value to `customer.CustomerID` like this :

```
public Customer Add(Customer customer)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO Customer(Name,Address) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES (@Name,@Address)";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", customer.Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", customer.Address);
                con.Open();
                customer.CustomerID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                con.Close();
            }
            return customer;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! Just one question...I know that ExecuteScalar is for getting one row, but wil it always do the job of ExecuteNonQuery? I thougth ExecuteScalar will only read data, but here it inserts it also.